# Proving that a linear application is an isomorphism if ond only if A can be inverted

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to solve for fun this exercise:
Let K be a field, and $f: K^n \to K^n $ a linear application and A square matrix that:

$$f(x_1, ..., x_n)^T = A (x_1, ..., x_n)^T $$

Prove that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if A can be inverted, and describe $f^{-1}$.

I will highly appreciate your help, because I am relatively new to algebra but very passionate with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

Assume first $A$ can be inverted. We need to show $f$ is an isomorphism (1-to-1 and onto).

Let $x,y \in K^n$ and assume $f(x) = f(y)$. Then, $Ax = Ay$. Remember we are assuming $A$ is invertible, can you show $x=y$?

Let $x \in K^n$. To prove $f$ is onto it suffices to find the preimage of $x$ in $K^n$ under $f$. Let $y = A^{-1}x$. Certainly, $y \in K^n$. Note that $$f(y) = Ay = A \left(A^{-1}x\right) = \left(AA^{-1}\right)x = x.$$ Can you now conclude $f$ is onto?

---

Now assume $f(x) = Ax$ is an isomorphism, so $f$ is 1-to-1 and onto.

Use 1-to-1 to show that $f$ has a trivial kernel, i.e. $f(x) = 0$ has a unique solution $x = 0$. Conclude that columns of $A$ are linearly independent. (**Further Hint:** if columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, prove that $f$ has non-trivial kernel by constructing a non-zero element that $f$ must map to 0. The contrapositive of this is what you want to show.)

Use onto to show that $A$ must have $n$ columns.

Comment: Thanks for your comment gt6989b, I understood how to prove that f is 1-to-1, but I still don't know how to prove that f is onto, how can you tell that f is onto by $ y=A^-1 x $?

Comment: I also understood using 1-to-1 to prove that f has trivial kernel, but how do you conclude that columns of A are linearly independent?

Comment: @OscarLaraCrosas please see updates in the 2 places you were asking for in further hints

Comment: And how do you use onto to prove that A must have n columns? And ho do you use this and that A columns are linearly independent toshow that A is invertible? I've been thinking really hard but still can't find out. Thanks for your help

Comment: @OscarLopez if $A$ has less columns, it cannot span the space - the basis of the span is at most the number of linearly independent columns. If a matrix is full rank you can row-reduce it to the identity matrix, which helps to show it is invertible.